# Using the Null Coalesce Operator for chained calls

Tags: php

I want to use the null coalesce operator like this

`$response['shares']->getField('count') ?? 0`

What this should do is to get the share count or if its not set get 0. The problem I'm having now is, that sometimes the array index `shares` does not exist so I'm getting `ErrorException: Undefined index: shares`. I know that I could do it like this

`isset($response['shares']) ? $response['shares']->getField('count') : 0` but is there a way to do that with the null coalesce operator directly without checking every index for its existence?

Comment: No. Since first you can't call a method on something which doesn't exists. So if you try to check if it exists first with `$response['shares'] ?? ...` then it would return that if it exists and you won't be able to call the method.

Comment: So I would need to go the old way here?

Comment: You can't call a method on a non existent index, so yes you have.